# Send a double with SharedPreferences to another activity

Tags: android-studio

I'm trying to send a value from the first activity to the last activity.
After some calculation (depending of the input of the user) The value a5 is example 2500.
I store it in a string and try to send it, but in the other activity it always give me a value of 100 and not the original 2500.

Code:
First Activity:

```html
// After some calculation a5 is a 2500
double a5 = a1 / 30;


        details.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String value = Double.toString(a5);
                SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("myKey", MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
                editor.putString("value", value);
                Log.d("myTag", "Value: " + value); // this is correct and gives me the right value
                openActivity3();
            }
        });
```

Last Activity:

```html
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_details);

        Textview= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.WarframeLvl);

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("myKey", MODE_PRIVATE);
        String value = sharedPreferences.getString("value","");

        Log.d("myTag", "TValue received: " + value); // I see a value of 100

        Textview.setText(value); //The textview changes and gives me the number 100 instead of the correct number.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("myKey", MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
            editor.putString("value", value);
            editor.commit();
```

You forget to to call save function. Check above.

Comment: @Elgan I have no idea for that. You probably missed something during in question. Because other stuff seems fine.

Comment: @Elgan You can vote or accept answer as Thank you. Just FYI.